# How to make a smooth XML Parsing for Tags & sub tags within it...?

Tags: iphone

I have to parse number of tags & sub tags also in XML format, then how it can be possible to make it smooth at the time of parsing & fetching data to display?

Please suggest the proper way of getting it parsed.

Comment: Would you edit your question to include more detail? What is _smooth XML parsing_? Also, what have you found in your research to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

//USE NSXMLParser

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_URL"]];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
```

// Below are the delegates which will get you the data

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"forecast_conditions"]){
    getData = YES; // getData is a bool which is NO initialy
}

if(getData)
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"day_of_week"])
        NSLog(@"%@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"]);

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"low"])
        NSLog(@"%@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"]);

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"high"])
        NSLog(@"%@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"]);

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"icon"])
        NSLog(@"%@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"]);

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"condition"])
        NSLog(@"%@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"data"]);
     }
}

  -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    }

  -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"forecast_conditions"]){
           getData = NO;
       }

   }
```

Comment: Have you seen the link....?

It is having a number of main Tags & also the number of sub tags are there.

If you have a time that you can spent on it to explain me & can say me how can i Parse this web service to get data smoothly then it is good to me...

I am confuse to use NSMutableDictionary or NSMutableString to be added in the NSMutableArray.

From both of the above which is the better option to use...?

Thanks in advance Naveen...

Comment: give me your email id i'll send you a demo project

Comment: @JigneshFadadu bro check your mail inbox

Comment: the project i send you run that project and in your xcode check the console. all data is loged there. where are you getting problem

Comment: ok and i made this in 4.3.1 and it is arc enabled. i m going to change my answer according to your xml file alter the code according to you. and one more thing your xml is not a proper though